# Datatables row editable with CellEdit dynamic options in R Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, datatables, dt

This is really a general question, so I do not have a reprex. Using [CellEdit](https://github.com/ejbeaty/CellEdit/tree/master), does anyone know how to replace the dropdown options of an 'list' input with an **R dataframe/vector that contains a single column**. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60663617/manually-edit-child-row-in-shiny-datatable) is example of how this can be done, using `sprintf()` -- inserting R code in Javascript. I am unsure how to do this since my JS skills are not that good.

```
  "table.MakeCellsEditable({",
  "  onUpdate: onUpdate,",
  "  inputCss: 'my-input-class',",
  "  confirmationButton: {",
  "    confirmCss: 'my-confirm-class',",
  "    cancelCss: 'my-cancel-class'",
  "  },",
  "  inputTypes: [",
  "    {",
  "      column: 0,",
  "      type: 'list',",
  "      options: [",
  "        {value: 'Keep data', display: 'Keep data'},",
  "        {value: 'Pass', display: 'Pass'},",
  "        {value: 'Delete', display: 'Delete'}",
  ## PASS THE ABOVE DROPDOWN OPTIONS FROM R INSTEAD OF HARDCODED IN JS
  "      ]",
  "    }",
  "  ]",
  "});"
```

I am referencing the code from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66004405/access-updated-datatable-edited-with-celledit-in-r-shiny/66007497#66007497) on SO.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you elaborate on what you mean by "dynamic"?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent -- Hi, thanks for responding. Sorry for the confusion. I restated the issue. Please see the above post again.

Comment: Do you mean that here for example, the column of the dataframe would be `c("Keep data", "Pass", "Delete")`?

Comment: Exactly. If the above dropdown options ("Keep data", etc.) were an R vector or dataframe, how would I go about passing that as the options in the dropdown? This is another example I was reviewing to try and do that -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52593539/edit-datatable-in-shiny-with-dropdown-selection-for-factor-variables but using CellEdit.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your options are in the R vector `opts`, you can do:

```r
opts <- c("Keep data", "Pass", "Delete")

jsOpts <- paste0(
  sprintf("{value: '%s', display: '%s'}", opts, opts), 
  collapse = ", "
)

js <- c(
  "table.MakeCellsEditable({",
  "  onUpdate: onUpdate,",
  "  inputCss: 'my-input-class',",
  "  confirmationButton: {",
  "    confirmCss: 'my-confirm-class',",
  "    cancelCss: 'my-cancel-class'",
  "  },",
  "  inputTypes: [",
  "    {",
  "      column: 0,",
  "      type: 'list',",
  "      options: [",
  jsOpts,
  "      ]",
  "    }",
  "  ]",
  "});"
)
```

Comment: @olb18 Glad to help. Please consider accepting the answer (by clicking the checkmark), and upvoting it if you want.